# Using Moles to mock user-made classes

Tags: .net, mocking, moles

I have searched the forums and all over the web and have not really seen a straight answer for this.

I have just been introduced to moles and I read that it can mock any .NET class or function call. However, I am wondering if it is possible to use Moles to mock classes that I have created myself.

I have used MOQ before and I have read that some people use both Moles and [insert other mocking framework] in tandem but I was thinking it would be more convenient to stick with just one.

So my central question is this:

Can Moles be used to mock classes/functions that I created myself?

edit: I have seen the process done several times with DateTime and creating a .moles file with the mscorlib in the xml file. Since a user-made class does not come from a .NET library, how is this done?

Comment: There's nothing special about framework code.  A class that you create is just like any other class in the framework (more or less).  Ergo, if you can "mole" any class in the framework, you ought to be able to "mole" your own classes as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as you said, Moles can mock any .NET type including types created by the end user.

---

**Update:**

After installing Moles:

1. Create a new class library project to hold the unit tests for the code you want to test;
2. On this project add a reference to the library or executable containing the code that will be under test;
3. Build the test project in order to copy the referenced library to the local output directory;
4. Right-click the added reference to invoke context menu where you will be presented with the option to Add Moles Assembly.

Comment: In examples I have seen (all of them are about mocking DateTime) and they use moles to create an xml file and change a line to say

    AssemblyName="mscorlib"

Since a user-made class does not come from a .NET library, I am not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: You shouldn't need to change anything in the xml file, it should work just fine.